# Using .addDateExclusion()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm creating school class calendar with repeating events, how do I use .addDateExclusion(new Date()), I tried a lot of combinations none of witch worked

```
function makeCalendar(name, begin, end, calendar) {
    var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar).createEventSeries(
        name,
        begin,
        end,
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
        .addDateExclusion(new Date(2019, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        .addWeeklyRule().interval(2).until(krajdat)
    );
}
```

EDIT 1:
This is only ting that actually worked

```
function makeCalendar(name, begin, end, calendar) {
    var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar).createEventSeries(
        name,
        begin,
        end,
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
        .addDateExclusion(begin)
        .addWeeklyRule().interval(2).until(krajdat)
    );
}
```

code above does what it is supposed to do that is ignore first occurrence, but whatever I did to that date like adding days didn't work

EDIT 2:

```
    var d = new Date(begin);
    d.setMonth(9);
    d.setDate(9);

var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar).createEventSeries(
        name,
        begin,
        end,
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
        .addDateExclusion(d)
        .addWeeklyRule().interval(2).until(krajdat)
    );
```

This actually worked, but setting full year didn't.
Still not optimal result because I want to pass recurrence to function, but we are getting somewhere.

EDIT 3:

I think the problem here are actually time zones, I looked the logs and that was the only difference between working and non working dates.

Comment: What are you passing for the `begin` parameter? Can you add `Logger.log(begin);` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: I am passing date object;  output:    Mon Sep 03 14:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018

Comment: That date is in the past. (Mon Sep 03 14:00:00 GMT+02:00 **2018**), but I see you got it working via a different method!

Comment: It is in past, but it is an recurring event so it lasts until june

Comment: Huh. When I read the documentation it's sounds like it would only exclude one specific date. "Adds a rule that excludes an occurrence for a specific date."

Comment: Yes it does exclude just one date, but i can go back and see it excluded, that was just a test tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found error, problem were time zones that i needed to set in preferences .addDateExclusion() doesn't work if used with different time zones.